# Need to click the button twice to edit and update gridview data

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

In my application i need to edit the gridview rows on clicking the edit button of that particular row everything works fine edit update and cancel the problem is when i click edit button my gridview disappears again to see the gridview i should click the below button

`<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="border:1px solid #456879;border-radius:5px;height: 22px;Width:150px" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Get Uploaded Data" Width="132px" />` 
and similarly after updating my gridview disappears but update happens so to again see the gridview i should again click the above button Get Uploaded Data,Finally in order to edit gridview data i need to click the button twice and in order to see the updated data  again i need to click the button twice.How can i solve this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CellPadding="3" Font-Size="12px" Width="300px" Visible="false" OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView2_RowUpdating" OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView2_RowCancelingEdit" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"> 
                    <Columns> 
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="Images/icon-edit.png" Height="32px" Width="32px"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="Images/update1.jpg"/>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="Images/cancel.jpg"/>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>             
                        <asp:templatefield headertext="sno">
                        <itemtemplate>
                            <asp:label id="lblid" runat="server" text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>'></asp:label>
                        </itemtemplate>
                        <edititemtemplate>           
                            <asp:label id="lbleditid" runat="server" text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>'></asp:label>           
                        </edititemtemplate>
                    </asp:templatefield>    
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>           
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>           
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Salary">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSalary" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Salary") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>           
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditSalary" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Salary") %>'></asp:TextBox>           
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDesignation" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Designation") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>           
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditDesignation" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Designation") %>'></asp:TextBox>           
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Location") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>           
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditLocation" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Location") %>'></asp:TextBox>           
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>           
                 </asp:GridView>
```

.Cs Code

```
protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        GridView2.Visible = true;

    }
    protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblEditID = (Label)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblEditID");
        TextBox txtEditName = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditName");
        TextBox txtEditSalary = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditSalary");
        TextBox txtEditDesignation = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditDesignation");
        TextBox txtEditLocation = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditLocation");
        con.Open();
        string cmdstr = "update CodingLog1 set Name=@Name,Salary=@Salary,Designation=@Designation,Location=@Location where ID=@ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", lblEditID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtEditName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", txtEditSalary.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", txtEditDesignation.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", txtEditLocation.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView2.Visible = true;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
    protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void GridView2_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
          GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
          GridView2.Visible = true;
          GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

Button code-

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = null; GridView1.DataBind();
        string desi = Session["Role"].ToString();
        string user = Session["Username"].ToString();
        string selecteduser = ddlusers.SelectedItem.Text;

        if (TextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            if (rdupldeddate.Checked == true)
            {
                DataTable dt = adm.GetRecordsByUploadedDate(user, TextBox1.Text, desi, selecteduser);  //Uploaded date

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (desi == "Supervisor")
                    {
                        BtnExport.Visible = true;
                        GridView2.Visible = true;
                        GridView1.Visible = false;
                        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView2.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GridView2.Visible = false;
                        BtnExport.Visible = false;
                        GridView1.Visible = true;
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                else { lblMsg.Visible = true; GridView1.Visible = false; GridView2.Visible = false; lblMsg.Text = "No Data Present!!!"; }
            }
            else
            {
                DataTable dt = adm.GetRecordsByCodedDate(user, TextBox1.Text, desi, selecteduser);  //CodedDate
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (desi == "Supervisor")
                    {
                        BtnExport.Visible = true;
                        GridView2.Visible = true;
                        GridView1.Visible = false;
                        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView2.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GridView2.Visible = false;
                        BtnExport.Visible = false;
                        GridView1.Visible = true;
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                else { lblMsg.Visible = true; GridView1.Visible = false; GridView2.Visible = false; lblMsg.Text = "No Data Present!!!"; }
            }
        }
        else { lblMsg.Visible = true; lblMsg.Text = "Please Enter Date!!!"; }

    }
```

I had tried all the possibilties by taking editindex=0 instead of -1, by calling my gridview2.databind in !ispostback moreover i had placed my gridview in update panel also but still its not working

Comment: Do you have any code in `Page_Load` that sets the visibility of these two GridViews?  If so, could you show that code?

Comment: below is my page load code    lblMsg.Text = "";
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindUsers();
        }
        string desi = Session["Role"].ToString();
        if (desi == "Supervisor")
        {
            GridView2.Visible = true;
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            ddlusers.Visible = true;
            BtnExport.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GridView2.Visible = false;
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            ddlusers.Visible = false;
            BtnExport.Visible = false;
        }

Comment: based on the designations i am hiding grids and necessary controls in page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your GridView2_RowUpdating, you are updating your data on the database and binding your GridView2 to nothing. That's why the GridView disappears. It has no data to show. While the button you click fetch the updated data and binds it to the GridView that's why it shows again. When you update the data, you should fetch the updated data and rebind it to your GridView again.

I suggest using DataSet and assign as Datasource before calling GridView2.DataBind();

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr ,con);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", lblEditID.Text);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtEditName.Text);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", txtEditSalary.Text);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", txtEditDesignation.Text);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", txtEditLocation.Text);   

DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();

da.Fill(dsResult);
con.Close();

GridView2.DataSource = dsResult;
GridView.DataBind();
```

Or Call the codes in your button through a method after the update.
Try this if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you pasted into the comments, the problem lies in your `Page_Load` event handler.  The code that sets the initial visibility of the GridViews should be inside the `if (!IsPostBack)` block.

```
lblMsg.Text = ""; 

if (!IsPostBack) 
{ 
    BindUsers();

    // Set the initial visibility of grids here
    string desi = Session["Role"].ToString(); 

    if (desi == "Supervisor") 
    { 
        GridView2.Visible = true; 
        GridView1.Visible = false; 
        ddlusers.Visible = true; 
        BtnExport.Visible = false; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        GridView2.Visible = false; 
        GridView1.Visible = true; 
        ddlusers.Visible = false; 
        BtnExport.Visible = false; 
    }
}
```

Once you have set the visibility for those grids on the first page load, that setting will be maintained by the ViewState across postbacks.  From that point on, it appears that your control events are managing the visibility of the grids (based on whether there are results to show, etc).

Comment: but still i am facing the same issue